# How do I list all available context variables?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I'm new to django templates, and I'm trying to tweak the admin interface. Right now I'm editing tabular.html in order to control how inlines are displayed. However, I have no idea what variables are available via the context the admin app sends to this template. Is there any quick way to see all variables available?

I know it is possible to use assert False in a .py-file, is there some equivalent in a template file?

Answer (score 10):

Use Django debug toolbar and make sure settings.py has:

```
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'SHOW_TEMPLATE_CONTEXT': True,
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Django debug toolbar](http://github.com/dcramer/django-debug-toolbar) - it includes a panel that shows the context of all templates used to render the current page.

Comment: Hmm, I downloaded and installed the debug toolbar from http://github.com/dcramer/django-debug-toolbar, but I cannot seem to find the context variables. Any idea? I followed their install instructions exactly.

Comment: @Kristian - did you ever figure this out? I just found that if I add ` 'SHOW_TEMPLATE_CONTEXT':True ` as @aaron suggested and open the 'templates' panel there will be a '> Toggle context' under each template. That is how you can view what context is available... PER template.

Comment: The toolbar is now (dec '14) at: https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar